# How to configure tomahawk and trinidad to work together

Tags: jsf

I am new to JSF. I want to use inputListOfValues component from Trinidad in my application which also uses Tomahawk.

I have added the required jars for Trinidad and before getting inputListOfValues I tried one simple inputText to be printed on browser using Trinidad.

I was not getting any configuration errors but it was not printing the corresponding text on browser. So I wonder if I can use tomahawk and trinidad together ?

If yes, is there any configuration setting we need to do for this ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 1):

Both are just *component libraries*. They ought to work fine together. You should more worry about the compatibility of Trinidad with your current JSF *implementation* (Sun RI/Mojarra or Apache MyFaces). As per the information at the [Trinidad homepage](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/) you need at least a JSF 1.1 implementation for Trinidad 1.1, JSF 1.2 for Trinidad 1.2 and JSF 2.0 for Trinidad 2.0.

Which Trinidad version did you download? Which JSF implementation and version are you using? Align it out.